# How to structure/control the data that was submitted by a Form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's assume I have a Form like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>
            Submit?
        </th>
        <th>
            Data
        </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="c1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="t1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="c2">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="t2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

If I submit that form. An Array will be submitted that contains the checkboxes (if checked) and the regular input.

Now I want it to either:

- Submit each row as a row in the array
- Only submit the content of the row if the checkbox is checked.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

**Edit:**

Right now I am submitting the Data like this:

```
$.post(url, { attributes: $(form).serializeArray() })
```

I'd love to do it with HTML-Markup, if possible. As this would be the right way in my opinion.

I actually don't want to do some JS/PHP Array juggling. Unless there is a nice way to do it. Right now I can only think of some quite ugly foreach stacking.

Comment: Sure there is. How are you submitting this data - regular form submit or ajax? Do you want to do this client side (js) or serverside (php)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I guess it's not possible to do this without using bigger javascript parts, because if you want to filter the data before sending them to the PHP it has to be somehow done and you can't do that with HTML. But in my opinion it's not ugly to do this with some jQuery, it's necessary and can also be done elegant.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, your ideal solution is to submit the form normally (page refresh) rather than using ajax (as you currently do)?

Comment: @Johannes Well may be you are right. This could be done most probably quite elegant using jQery. And execute an AJAX call independent from any Form Submission.

Comment: @user574632 Well I think this would be the perfect solution. But as this seems to be impossible I will just go with a jQuery/Ajax solution. That will most probably do a nice job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here is how I solved it:

Leave the form as it is.

Just do some JS Magic. Instead submitting the Form I do the following:

```
var submitData = {};

$("input:checked.attributCheckbox").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    // This is how I get the input for the checkbox.
    var val = $("input[type=number][name="+ id +"]").val();

    submitData[id] = val;
});

$.post(url, {attributes : submitData});
```

Well it's not the perfect solution I hoped for. But it works quite nice. Maybe somebody can come up with a better way to solve it?